# using an IF type statement in c# .net aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm much more of a SQL guy but wanted to know if there is an IF type equivalent in .NET?

Basically I want it so that if a person is on website 1 then they are assigned a bespoke jscript tag and if they move to site 2 the jscript tag changes to the one for that site

example

```
IF storeID=1 then jscript tag = <script src='//d3c3cq12345psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-22222-1000000.js'>
If StoreID02 then jscript tag = <script src='//d3c3cq99999psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-11111-1000000.js'>
```

But obviously not in a SQL type way.

Anybody give me a pointer?

Comment: you can register certain script at ScriptManager based on your condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your `if` in [embedded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX):

```
<% if(storeID=1) { %>
   <script src='//d3c3cq12345psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-22222-1000000.js'>
<% } %>
<% else if(storeID=2) { %>
   <script src='//d3c3cq99999psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-11111-1000000.js'>
<% } %>
```

Comment: **NB** that's for `.aspx` files. For `.cshtml` and `.vbhtml` the syntax is rather different.

Comment: @Richard: you are right. The question references ASPX, so it should work in this case. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. you can do something like this..

```
<% if (storeID == 1) { %>
    <script src='//d3c3cq12345psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-22222-1000000.js'>
<% } %>
```

..etc.